# How to Delete by clicking on it..?

Tags: javascript, php, html, angular

I have one table content in which I have created view of it's list and performing the edit and deleting task on it.

I am trying it by calling in services the `splice` method and in the component it's service by id.

**table.component.ts**:

```
 delete(com) {
    this.service.DeleteUser(com);
    console.log(com);
}
```

**table.component.html**:

```
<a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm" (click)="delete(com.id)">Delete</a>
```

**service**:

```
 DeleteUser(index: number) {
    this.company.splice(index, 1);
    this.company_change.next(this.company.slice());
  }
```

I want to get delete button on working condition,`company:Company[]` list is been created by type `model`.

Comment: Did you get the deleted index on that console?

Comment: yes i am getting index on console.

Comment: but it's not deleting specific

Comment: could you please put the code on stackblitz?

Comment: yes putting it to stackblitz

Comment: please give me the link

Comment: actually i am doing on my local and not know more about stackblitz it's giving me error ,though i sent you with the bug's.

Comment: try passing index variable instead of com.id. (click)="delete(i)"

Comment: Seba,thanks for sharing it. code worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

replace the com.id with i in the click function delete

```
<tr class="table-active" *ngFor="let com of company;  let i = index">
        <td>{{com.co_name}}</td>
        <td>{{com.co_profile}}</td>
        <td>{{com.co_address}}</td>
        <td>{{com.co_email}}</td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm" [routerLink]="['/table',com.id]">
            Edit
          </a>
          <a class="btn btn-outline-danger  btn-sm" (click)="delete(i)">Delete</a>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: actually now i want to make a call of modal and from that pass the delete query ,how's so that possible

Answer (score 1):

As you are passing company `id` (not index) here `(click)="delete(com.id)"`, you have to filter the company list to find the index (i) of the company whose id matches the id you have passed and then splice the company list based on the index.

Try like this:

```
 DeleteUser(id: number) {

    for(let i=0;i<this.company.length;i++) {
      if(this.company[i].id == id) {
        this.company.splice(i, 1)
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: trying it with modal but not getting it;s id,it ' been giving me Nan value.

Comment: Which one is NaN?? Can u share stackbiltz

Comment: actually i am new to stackbltiz and i don't know to use it.

Comment: i want to navigate and try it with ,what should i do.?

Comment: Okay then, console `id`, `this.company[i]` and show what is NaN

Comment: it's deleting list first entry not selected.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more

Comment: when i am clicking to delete,the list which is been getting to view is been deleting first,by first and in console there is showing undefined.

Comment: and adrita i am doing the way seba upper fellow told to replace the content and it's being happeing ,but in the modal it's been not getting the id

Comment: In short i have'nt called the filter just replaced com.id with i,now forgett,when i am redirecting to modal it should delete from the modal how to get it actually..?

Comment: Sorry @jayshah I am unable to understand the scenerio, I think you should try with stackbiltz